# C# string method for exact match on multiple params

Tags: c#

Is there a standard **String** method that can take multiple parameters for exact comparison?

The equivalent in **T-SQL** would be **IN('dog','cat',...)**

Eg, if there was such a method called *EqualToAny()* then the below code should return false

```
string s="catfish";
if (s.EqualToAny("dog", "cat", "human", "dolphin"))
   return true;
else
   return false;
```

Comment: Explain "partial match"...  If you use `ContainsAny`, it's not, for example, going to return true if the string contains just "huma", only if it contains "human".

Comment: In your example what exactly is `s`?

Comment: _so catfish should be false_ makes little sense. Provide clear inputs with desired outputs.

Comment: By "partial match" do you mean that a match must have a word boundary?  In other words whitespace, punctuation, start of string, end of string, etc?

Comment: You mean that instead of `s == "dog" || s == "cat" || s == "human"` you want `new [] { "dog", "cat", "human" }.Contains(s)`?

Comment: What's the problem with this: `string[] animals = {"dog", "cat", "human", "dolphin"};
if (animals.Contains(s)))
{
   // ...
}`

Comment: @HenkHolterman The more I read this the more I'm confused by _I want the below code to return true for mammals_

Comment: _but ContainsAny returns true_ isn't very clear either.

Comment: As I said under Dmitry's answer, I think the question is ambiguous. I read it as it should return true for "I have a cat name bob." and false for "I have a catfish named bob."

Comment: **And why hasn't there been any input from the OP??**  Time to close this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need EqualsAny ..

```
    // string extension method 
    public static bool EqualsAny(this string source, params  string[] prms)
    {
        return prms.Contains(source);
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, that's just what I want.  I was just hoping there already was a method to do this.

Comment: @userSteve -- I want to point out that you have failed miserably to participate in this forum as all of the attempts to clarify your question went unanswered by you.  It's very frustrating considering the number of people who were trying to help you which you completely ignored.

Comment: @rory.ap I agree my original question could have been better formed and am very happy there were so many responses so quickly, but it really was a matter of only a few minutes!  It's not like days have past!

Comment: @userSteve -- Well, that's how this site operates.  If you aren't around to clarify your question, it gets down voted and closed very quickly and then forgotten.  I don't recommend posting and then walking away.  Only post when you're ready to sit there and respond.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this using the Linq `Any()` method.

```
string input = "catfish";
var mammals = new [] {"dog", "cat", "human", "dolphin"};
var result = mammals.Any(v => v == input);
```

`result` will be `false` for `"catfish"` and `true` for `"cat"`.

You can also wrap this into an extension method for string:

```
public static bool EqualsAny(this string str, IEnumerable<string> validStrings) {
    return validStrings.Any(v => v == str);
}

var result = input.EqualsAny(mammals);
```

[Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/0WZoVB)

Comment: The question is not clear, but it might actually be that the OP wants something more like `mammals.Any(v => input.Contains(v))` but then there seems to be a desire to have "cat" only match if there are word boundaries like "I have a cat", but not for something like "I eat catfish".

Comment: It looks like OP is looking for a method on the string object, not on the collection.

Comment: Now based on the edit this is correct, but of course you could have just done `mammals.Contains(input)`.

Comment: Yes, `Contains` will also work if we do not need any fancy string comparison (e.g. `v => v.Equals(str, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)`)